# ¿Como autocompletar bash en windows 10?

Tags: bash, autocompletar

Tengo instalado la distribución de Ubuntu en Windows 10 y cuando tengo la carpeta Desktop no me autocompleta si escribo desk..., o sea que lo hace solo si empiezo con mayúsculas (Desk...), lo cuál es muy molesto además de hacer un ruido aún más molesto.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que no autocompleta al presionar `tab` en el terminal?

Comment: Hola @carlos. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Además, puede consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda. También, puede consultar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: tal como lo comentas, parece que si escribes "desk" y pulsas la tecla tab no te autocompleta, pero si escribes "Desk" y pulsas tab entonces si autocompleta... Si ese es el caso entonces te recuerdo que en linux se distinguen mayusculas y minusculas, no es lo mismo "Desktop" que "desktop". Puede ser que el bash en este caso actue como tal, y eso no se consideraria un mal funcionamiento, seria como se trabaja.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un **alias** o una **variable de entorno** para modificar la forma en que te relacionas con los nombres.

Comment: Evita hacer respuesta de este tipo, de lo contrario haz una explicación mas extensa y con ejemplos. Cuando tengas mayor reputación podrás comentar